# Replacing "function" by "binary relation" in ZFC's axiom schema of replacement

Tags: logic, set-theory, first-order-logic, axioms

$\text{ZFC}$'s axiom schema of replacement states, informally, that whenever $\varphi$ is a function and $s$ is a set, the image $\varphi[s] = \big\{y :\ \exists x \in s.\ \langle x,y\rangle \in \varphi\big\}$ is a set. Suppose we don't require $\varphi$ to be a function but an arbitrary binary relation. Is the resulting theory still $\text{ZFC}$?

More precisely, the axiom schema of replacement is the following collection of sentences in the language of first order logic:

> For every
>
> - well-formed formula $\varphi$ in the language of first-order predicate logic,
> - $5$ distinct variables $s, t, x, y, z$ of the language of first-order predicate logic such that the free variables of $\varphi$ $\subseteq \{x,y\}$,
>
> $\Big(\forall x\exists y\big(\varphi \wedge \forall z(\varphi[z/y] \implies z = y)\big)\Big) \implies \Big(\forall s\exists t\forall y\big(y \in t \iff \exists x(x \in s \wedge \varphi)\big)\Big)\tag{*}$

Denote by $\text{ZFC}'$ the collection of sentences of first order predicate logic that are determined by the axioms and axiom schemas of $\text{ZFC}$ without the axiom schema of replacement, and denote by $R'$ the collection of sentences of first order predicate logic that result from the modified axiom schema of replacement obtained by omitting the antecedent in $(*)$.

Then every theorem of $\text{ZFC}$ is a theorem of $\text{ZFC}' \cup R'$. Is the converse true? In other words, is every theorem of $\text{ZFC}' \cup R'$ a theorem of $\text{ZFC}$?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_schema_of_replacement#Axiom_schema_of_collection

Comment: @AsafKaragila: Thanks! This is new to me. However, I think the axiom schema of collection described in the Wikipedia article is not quite the axiom schema R' I described in my question, since R' states, informally, that whenever $\varphi$ is a binary relation, the following is a set: $\varphi[s] = \big\{y :\ \exists x \in s.\ \langle x,y\rangle \in \varphi\big\}$, whereas the axiom schema of collection, if I understand correctly, says, informally, that whenever $\varphi$ is a binary relation, there exists a certain subset of $\varphi[s]$, but it needs not be all of $\varphi[s]$.

Comment: What if $\varphi(x,y)\equiv y=y$? Or, for immediate Russel-fun, $y\notin y$?

Comment: I didn't notice that, and in that case, @Hagen points out the obvious flaw, it is easy to arrange for a relation whose range on any singleton is a proper class. In that case, Collection is exactly why you want to say that there is a "set restriction" kind of, to avoid that situation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is a simple task to show in $\mathsf{ZFC'}$. that
$$ \tag1\exists s\,\exists x\,x\in s.$$
Let $\varphi$ be the well-formed formula
$$ y\in y.$$
Then 
$$ \forall s\,\exists t\,\forall y\,(y\in t\leftrightarrow\exists x\,(x\in s\land \varphi),$$
specialized to an $s$ as in $(1)$, gives us 
$$ \exists t\,\forall y\,(y\in t\leftrightarrow \exists x\,(x\in s\land y\notin y).$$
By $(1)$, this becomes 
$$ \exists t\,\forall y\,(y\in t\leftrightarrow y\notin y).$$
So for such $t$,
$$ \forall y\,(y\in t\leftrightarrow y\notin y)$$
and specialized to $t$,
$$t\in t\leftrightarrow t\notin t. $$
I sincerely hope that this is not a theorm of $\mathsf{ZFC}$.